# How to stop user from opening a website in another tab?

Tags: php, jquery

Like it happens in Banking sites....i want to implement the same thing in my website. Please help me how to go about it.

Comment: This is not really possible, since you have no control over the client side. Not sure what you actually mean by "Like it happens in Banking sites".

Comment: Like many banking sites logs you out of the website, if you copy paste the url in other tab.

Comment: Sounds pretty silly to me. Do not try to outsmart your users. Offer a robust service where such nonsense is not required instead :-) See: if a user really _wants_ to do something, then why do you want to prevent that? Isn't that the user's choice?

Comment: I need to implement this for security purposes...a lot of session updation happens when we traverse from one page to another.....i think you have never seen a banking site...i want a solution to it.  If they have implemented it there definitely exists a solution.

Comment: Certainly I know banking sites. But I do not see why using multiple tabs should be a security issue, _unless_ your site is programmed in a crappy style. That is what I meant above with "a robust service". A service that breaks or, even worse, fails on a security level just because the client tries requests in a pattern the service did not expect is insecure in itself. But certainly _not_ because the client uses multiple tabs. Sorry. Even without a single tab you have to expect the client to send _any_ sequence of requests without getting into trouble. Everything else is amateurish!

Comment: If you _really_ want to rely on such a "protection", then use a CSRF token. You will find lots of information about that on the internet. It is a basic pattern to prevent CSRF attacks which can be used for what you are talking about as a side effect. But as said: that won't make your site more secure. It is a _false_ sense of security you create. And that is worse than nothing. Why not really fix the security issues you are afraid of instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When the user signs in generate an access token on the server.
2. Store this token in SessionStorage.
3. When your page loads, check SessionStorage for the token and call a function on the server to validate it.
4. When the server is asked to generate a token for an account that already has a token, refuse to sign it in and return an error message instead.
5. Since the second tab then doesn't get signed in and there is a nice error message, it can fail with a proper message.

For this to work, you should also have a session timeout. So if the server issues a token and this token is not validated within your timeout (say, sixty seconds?), assume the connection is dead and refuse to validate subsequent use. At this point, the user can sign in from a second tab, since the first one is no longer signed in.